# How to Compare 2 Branches From Different Repositories Locally

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

Using GitKraken I want to compare 2 branches from 2 different repositories, however I can only see how to compare branches within the same repository.

Both of these repositories are pulled locally.

Comment: No need for any git tool, use a diff viewer (`meld`, `kdiff3` ...) to compare the 2 directories.

Comment: If you absolutely want to use the diff viewer of git kraken, check the doc to see if you can invoke just the diff viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Meld` was what I used for this and it works fantastically.

http://meldmerge.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can add the object databases as alternate sources and compare the tips by id. To do it temporarily, without affecting the originals at all, do it in a scratch clone:

```
git clone -s --bare /path/to/repo/a `mktemp -d`; cd $_
echo  >>objects/info/alternates  \
        $(cd /path/to/repo/b; cd $(git rev-parse --git-path objects); pwd)
git diff \
        $(git -C /path/to/repo/a rev-parse abranch) \
        $(git -C /path/to/repo/b rev-parse anotherbranch)
```

or if you want the refs appearing in your scratch clone you can remap the prefixes like

```
git fetch /path/to/repo/a refs/heads/*:refs/heads/repoa/*
git fetch /path/to/repo/b refs/heads/*:refs/heads/repob/*
```

which will copy nothing since all the objects are already accessible, and you can then

```
git diff repoa/main repob/feature
```

or whatever.